# jUnit not throw expected exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

I'm testing the following class:

```
@Service
public class ClassToBeTested {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ClassToBeTested(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void publicMethod(messageDto dto) {

        privateMethod(dto, param, "other string");
    }


    private void privateMethod(Object dto, String param, String param2) {
        
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            attributes = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto),
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        attributes.put("level", "error");
    }
}
```

and I'd like to make mapper throwing the JsonProcessingException. That's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContextConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    private ClassToBeTested classToBeTestedActor;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        classToBeTestedActor = new ClassToBeTested(mapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFailJsonParsing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Given
        final Dto dto = mock(Dto.class);

        // When
        when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any()))
                .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);

        // Then
        Assertions.assertThrows(JsonProcessingException.class,
                () -> classToBeTestedActor.publicMethod(dto));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the test fails. In particular, it seems that it is raised a `NullPointerException` on `attributes.put("level", "error");` and no `JsonProcessingException` is raised. Since that, the test fails.

Considering that `JsonProcessingException` should be thrown before the line affected by the `NullPointerException` it seems to me that the construct `when().thenThrow()` is not working fine.

Comment: your private method is catching and swallowing that jsonprocessingexception

Comment: had the same thought. How can I fix it?

Comment: why do you catch and swallow that exception? based on the next line `attributes.put("level", "error");`, you can't really recover from it. I would simply let the method throw the exception and let it propagate. Unless you need to define your own exceptions to add more context.

Comment: there are actually a couple of more lines that generate an alert to an external application. The exception catch is just for logging the event and generating an alert (not in the code now)

Comment: it remains that your `attributes.put` cannot just standing there outside of the catch block, as the object can be null (as you've seen with the NPE). In any case, if you want to test that the exception is thrown, you need to actually throw it out of the function

Comment: I tried to reason on your statements and I've moved out the exception on the public method. I'm thinking that the problem may be the mock of mapper, since it seems to be null. Should I do something else to ensure that the mapper never returns a null object?

Comment: If I follow what you've been doing, you are not mocking `readValue`, so it returns null.